# Visiting nodes in xsl

Tags: xslt

I am just getting started with xsl. Will describe below what I'm trying to accomplish, and hope someone can help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns1:GetSkillResponse>
    <ns1:Skill>
        <ns1:Person>
            <ns1:SkillId>001</ns1:SkillId>
        </ns1:Person>
        <ns1:Task Active="N">Value 1</ns1:Task>
        <ns1:Task Active="Y">Value 2</ns1:Task>
        <ns1:Task Active="Y">Value 3</ns1:Task>
    </ns1:Skill>
    <ns1:Skill>
        <ns1:Person>
            <ns1:SkillId>002</ns1:SkillId>
        </ns1:Person>
        <ns1:Task Active="Y">Value 1</ns1:Task>
        <ns1:Task Active="Y">Value 2</ns1:Task>
        <ns1:Task Active="Y">Value 3</ns1:Task>
    </ns1:Skill>
</ns1:GetSkillResponse>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:ns1="http://test">
    <xsl:template name="GetSkillResponse">
        <Message>
            <xsl:for-each select="/ns1:GetSkillResponse/ns1:Skill">
                <PropertySet>
                    <xsl:attribute name="MySkillId"><xsl:value-of select="ns1:Person/ns1:SkillId"/></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="MyTask"><xsl:value-of select="ns1:Task"/></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="MyActiveFlag"><xsl:value-of select="ns1:Task/@Active"/></xsl:attribute>
                </PropertySet>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Message>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This gets me:
001, Value 1, N
002, Value 1, Y

But I need to get:
001, Value 1, N
001, Value 2, Y
001, Value 3, Y
002, Value 1, Y
002, Value 2, Y
002, Value 3, Y

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want a separate entry for each `Task` element under `Skill`, and to do this, simply have a nested `xsl:for-each`.

For example...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns1="http://test">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="GetSkillResponse" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="GetSkillResponse">
        <Message>
            <xsl:for-each select="/ns1:GetSkillResponse/ns1:Skill">
                <xsl:for-each select="ns1:Task">
                    <PropertySet>
                        <xsl:attribute name="MySkillId"><xsl:value-of select="../ns1:Person/ns1:SkillId"/></xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="MyTask"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="MyActiveFlag"><xsl:value-of select="@Active"/></xsl:attribute>
                    </PropertySet>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Message>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note you can simplify this with [Attribute Value Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns1="http://test">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="GetSkillResponse" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="GetSkillResponse">
        <Message>
            <xsl:for-each select="/ns1:GetSkillResponse/ns1:Skill">
                <xsl:for-each select="ns1:Task">
                    <PropertySet MySkillId="{../ns1:Person/ns1:SkillId}" MyTask="{.}" MyActiveFlag="{@Active}"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Message>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```